# Is C99 fesetround()/fegetround() state per-thread or per-process?

Tags: c, floating-point, thread-safety, c99, c11

C and POSIX references I found online don't specify the thread-safety of C99's fesetround().  Even GNU documentation doesn't[1].  Is the state per-thread or per-process?

[1] https://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/libc.html#Rounding

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C11, which defines both threads and fesetround(), answers that it's per-thread. (Which is the only reasonable answer, but it had to be stated.)

Draft N1570 [1] section 7.6.2: "The floating-point environment has thread storage duration. The initial state for a thread’s floating-point environment is the current state of the floating-point environment of the thread that creates it at the time of creation."

[1] http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

Comment: Right; C99 didn't have a notion of "threads" or "thread storage duration", so it couldn't express this, but it was always the intent that the state be per-thread.